# How to set SQL Server Authentication Method in DataGrip?

Tags: sql-server, datagrip

Is there a way to specify the authentication method (SQL Server or Windows Authentication) when connecting to SQL Server with DataGrip?

I have tried configuring using both the SQL Server(jTDS) and the SQL Server(Microsoft) drivers and don't see an option on either.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**With the jTDS Driver:**

This is dependent on the settings for the connection/data source.

i.e. To set up a connection for Windows Authentication:

1. In the "**General**" tab, if specify your Windows/AD Username in the **User** field.
2. on the "**Advanced**" tab, in the **DOMAIN** property, specify the domain for the Windows account you put in Step 1.
3. You may need to set USENTLMV2=true if Kerberos authentication isn't enabled on your network

If you don't specify the domain in step 2, it will assume you are doing a SQL Server Authentication login attempt.

**With the Microsoft Driver:**

I couldn't get this to work on OS X, but most people seem to have no issues on Windows.

1. In the "**Advanced**" tab for the data source, set **integratedSecurity** to true.

n.b. you may have to also set this property for the actual Driver as well, on OS X i was getting continually "This driver is not configured for Integrated Authentication", but that could be OS X thing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had the same experience - works for jTDS driver, but not the Microsoft one.

Comment: Unfortunately 2016.1.1 does not have a DOMAIN property in the Advanced tab. Tried adding one via User Defined property but no luck connecting from Mac

Comment: Hi @rams i just updated to 2016.1.1 and i'm still seeing a DOMAIN property for the jTDS driver. it's towards the bottom of the list.

Comment: @pwae My mistake. I was using the wrong driver. With jTDS I do see the DOMAIN option. It's not available with the SQL Server driver.

Comment: I don't see how this has to do with OSX when it connects fine via other programs such as SQLPro for MSSQL. This is a DataGrip problem, not an OSX problem.

Comment: @StevenWade SQLPro for MSSQL (which i have also) uses FreeTDS, which is what the jTDS driver is based on. The noted problems with OS X, is just the Microsoft driver.

Comment: I'm adding PyCharm to this comment to make it easier for someone who doesn't realize that DataGrip is essentially what PyCharm uses to find this solution more easily.

Comment: `USENTLMV2` flag did the trick for me

Answer (score 7):

I was able to connect on MacOS in Intellij 2018.2 using the Microsoft 7.0.0 SQL Server jdbc driver.

(First, I'm assuming you have Kerberos working. To check that, run:

```
klist | grep krbtgt
```

If you have a Kerberos ticket, you should see:

```
Aug 29 12:17:34 2018  Aug 29 22:17:34 2018  krbtgt/DOMAIN.COMPANY.COM@DOMAIN.COMPANY.COM
```

I used this article on [Connecting using ActiveDirectoryIntegrated Authentication Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-2017#linux-and-mac) to troubleshoot this. Note that I did *not* have to do "Step 2: Configuring KDC in krb5.conf". )

Make sure to set the jdbc driver to use [integrated security and Java Kerberos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-kerberos-integrated-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#remarks).

[Picture of Advanced tab in Project Data Sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCcmu.png)

[Picture of Advanced tab in Project Data Sources showing authentication scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6P4na.png)

Then, on the general tab, make sure to change the drop down menu next to the URL, to "URL only" and put in a URL of the form:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://databaseserver.domain.company.com;database=testdatabase;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;
```

[Picture of General tab in Project Data Sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRbuk.png)

If you leave the drop down next to URL on "default", it will attempt to use a user name/password, which is not what you want if you're using integrated authentication. Also, please make sure you know what you're doing if you leave "trustServerCertificate=true;" in the URL. In production, you should properly setup your certificates, but that's not in the scope of what's being asked here.